# Is there a way to remove the option to minimize the application or maximize it, in pygame?

Tags: pygame

Is there a way to remove the option to minimize the application or maximize it, in pygame?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not make it able to be resized, only add your dimensions to the pygame.display.set_mode function. Do not add options. If what you mean by "removing the option to minimize the application or maximize it" is get rid of the button altogether, you can't do this. When you create a window in pygame, pygame creates a window with whatever window api is for your platform. Pygame doesn't get to decide how your window should look (menu-bar/options). This is why windows in macos and linux look different from windows in windows. To recap, you don't get to chose how your windows look. That's the job of whatever window manager api your system uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height), pg.NOFRAME)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply